# How to connect two headsets to one android mobile?

Tags: microphone

How to connect two headsets to one android mobile ? Me and my brother want to hear some songs but we have different headset. Please tell any hardware which is required so that we can connect 2 headsets to same Android mobile.

Comment: Get one of these: https://www.amazon.co.uk/TRIXES-3-5mm-Splitter-Audio-Headphone/dp/B002NPSTNU

Comment: This site is for electronic design, not for help using electronic devices. Please read the help section for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a coincidence !! I was asking some other question on this forum and the question you asked is subpart of that.
So Answer to your question is very simple - You needs "male TRRS to two female TRRS cable" adapter. Please find below the google link of that adapter -

[search link](https://www.google.com/search?q=male+TRRS+to+two+female+TRRS+cable&ei=XSB7YOTbCJWztQbJh7S4Dg&oq=male+TRRS+to+two+female+TRRS+cable&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABOgUIABCRAjoICAAQsQMQgwE6CwguELEDEMcBEKMCOgUIABCxAzoOCC4QsQMQgwEQxwEQowI6CggAELEDEIMBEEM6BAgAEEM6BwgAELEDEEM6BwguELEDEEM6DQguELEDEIMBEEMQkwI6BQguELEDOgQIABAKOgsILhCxAxDHARCvAToCCAA6BwgAELEDEAo6BggAEAcQHjoECAAQDToICAAQCBAHEB46BggAEAgQHjoGCAAQFhAeOgUIABCGAzoICCEQFhAdEB5Qp2ZY3qUCYLKpAmgDcAB4AIAB4wGIAcYekgEGNS4yOS4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwik_tSU7IXwAhWVWc0KHckDDecQ4dUDCA8&uact=5)

You need to plug that adapter to your Android mobile and then connect 2 headsets to other end of this adapter ! Enjoy !

Edit - If you want to buy that adapter, the link is shared by @winny in comment of your question.

Comment: Any particular for downvote ?

Comment: This site is for electronic design, not for help using electronic devices. Please read the help section for more information.

Comment: @Bort - Thanks. I will take care of that point in future.